# A-Frame Play and pause a sound by clicking on the same element

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm trying to make a sound play and pause by clickin the same element, I was able to play it but can't pause it and play it again every time I click, I'm Using javascript for this.

Here's what I have so far:

HTML

```
<a-image id="statue" src="#audio_logo" width="1.5" height="1.5" position="-27 7 -4" rotation="0 90 0" sound="src:#museumSound"> </a-image>
```

Javascript

```
  var sound = document.querySelector('#statue');
    sound.addEventListener('click', function () {
    sound.components.sound.playSound(); 
    });
```

Here I replicate the situation for better understanding, I what to be able to click the red square and play the sound and the click again on the same square and make it stop

https://codepen.io/EdgarJF/pen/jwdOZr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pausing the sound.

```
document.querySelector('#museumSound').pause();
```

Or

```
sound.components.sound.pauseSound();
```

Keep a boolean to know whether to play or pause.

```
var isPlaying = false; 
if (isPlaying) {
  // Do pause.
  isPlaying = false;
} else {
  // Do play.
  isPlaying = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, as I said, I'm really new to this and still learning, could you guide me on how the whole javascript should look? I mean where should your suggestions go?

Answer (score 0):

thx ngokevin! you also saved me and your suggestion worked perfectly in my case.

Dear Evoinsec
I can relate to you so much and have been lucky with ngokevin's help. so here I provide a part of my code.

Here is the HTML
        
  https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe-inspector.min.js">

```
    <a-marker preset="hiro">

        <!--This is to Start/Pause audio-->
        <a-image id="audio"
                 src="./img/bird.jpg"
                 width="1" height="1"
                 position="1 0 0"
                 rotation="90 0 -90"
                 sound="src:./sound/bird.mp3"></a-image>
     </a-marker>


    <a-entity camera>
        <a-entity id="myCursor" 
                  cursor="fuse:true; maxDistance:30; timeout:500;" 
                  scale="0.03 0.03 0.03" 
                  position="0 0 -2" 
                  geometry="primitive: ring" 
                  material="color: red; shader: flat; opacity:0.5">
        </a-entity>
    </a-entity>
   </a-scene>
</body>
```

Here is the .js
    function init() {
    document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener('click', audioControle, false);
    }

```
function audioControle() { //SOUND STATUS
  var sound = document.querySelector('#audio');
  if (isPlaying == true) {
    // Do pause.
    sound.components.sound.pauseSound(); 
    isPlaying = false;
  } else if (isPlaying == false){
    // Do play.
    sound.components.sound.playSound(); 
    isPlaying = true;
  }
init();
}
```

This is maybe not the smartest way but worked for me. I hope this helps you.